# How to calculate the Vertical Distance to Channel Network in ArcGis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, elevation, saga

In Saga there is the tool "Vertical Distance to Channel Network". Is there a way to produce the same data in ArcGIs? 
With con("flowacc" > xx, 1) I was able to create the Channel Network.
I am guessing that I have to subtract the channel networks elevation from the original elevation, but I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: Convert raster (DEM*streams) to points. Convert points to raster using long integer PointID. Calculate catchments for this raster using earlier derived flow direction. Convert catchments to polygons (no simplification) and transfer pour point elevation to field in polygons. Convert polygons to raster. DEM-last_result=required vertical distance

Comment: Raster calculator http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm or Minus http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Minus/009z00000093000000/ (spatial analyst required) will let you subtract one from the other. I'm not sure what the SAGA tool does, can you explain what you're after and perhaps we can emulate it in Esri.